# How to fix this TypeError for missing 'self' argument

Tags: python, oop, singleton

Getting TypeError on those methods where i used `self` as a param like `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. If the method have more than 1 arguments including `self` it shows similar error of missing another positional argument.

I started by making a singleton object that checks its own references to remain its singularity. I used `__new__` to do that.

### core.py

```
import pyglet.window

class Core(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls:
            cls = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls

    def __init__(self):
        self._instance = None
        self._window = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s object at %s>' % (Core.__name__, hex(id(Core)))

    def scene(self, width, height):
        self._window = pyglet.window.Window(width=width, height=height)
```

### script.py

```
from core import Core

c = Core()
print(c.__repr__())
c.scene(640, 480)
```

### errors:

```
    print(c.__repr__())
TypeError: __repr__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

    c.scene(640, 480)
TypeError: scene() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

This method is not the only case, so i want a understanding what is going on and how to fix this.
Thank you for your time.

### Edit:

It is not problem with only the`__repr__`. I want the other methods like `scene(self, width, height)` or any methods you could possibly create having `self` as one param. The second error for showing what error this code gives with other methods

I need the Core class to make a singleton object, so i can use other files to reference to this `Core._window` thing. I think this edited description can clarify what i wanted earlier. Sorry for convenience.

Comment: Remove self from function

Comment: This line `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):` should become like this: `def __new__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: @abdullah.cu Why is it? There is no instance object yet.

Comment: Call with print(repr(c)). Keep the self arg. 
"And c.__repr__() should work too". No it does not. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, `__new__` receives the class and is supposed to return the newly created object! As your code returns the class itself, thing go wrong. You should have:

```
class Core(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj
    ...
```

And anyway `__new__` is an advanced configuration, with is mainly used for immutable objects that cannot be configured in `__init__`. In your example you should just remove it:

```
class Core(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._instance = None
        self._window = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s object at %s>' % (Core.__name__, hex(id(Core)))
```

That is enough for common objects. You can indeed use `__new__` to build singletons, and even use it to build hierachies of singletons, meaning that every subclass of Core will be a singleton:

```
class Core(object):
    _obj = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._obj is None or not isinstance(cls._obj, cls):
            cls._obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._obj

    def __init__(self):
        self._instance = None
        self._window = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s object at %s>' % (Core.__name__, hex(id(self)))
```

Please note that my class `__repr__` uses `id(self)` to identify the object and not the class.

Demo:

```
>>> c = Core()
>>> d = Core()
>>> c is d
True
>>> class Child(Core):
    pass

>>> ch = Child()
>>> ch is c
False
>>> ch2 = Child()
>>> ch2 is ch
True
```

Comment: But this does not make it a Singleton.

Comment: It looks like one because you are identifying the Class object, not self with the OP custom repr. I suspect he wants id(self) not id(Core).

Comment: Wow! This approach does work, along with the desired funtionalities. Thanks.

Comment: @SergeBallesta why do you add `or not isinstance(cls._obj, cls)`?. Looks unnecessary to me.

Comment: @progmatico: it is what allows `Core` to be used as a base class for singleton subclasses: each subclass has its own `_obj` member.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is use `repr` like this:

```
repr(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works. Take a look here:

```
class Core(object):

    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s object at %s>' % (Core.__name__, hex(id(self)))

core = Core()
print(id(core))

core1 = Core()
print(id(core1))

print(repr(core))
print(repr(core1))
```

Comment: I tried this but this does not gives me desired operation. Because this way I need to to reference other variables of the class by hard-coding for all variables. This is why i want to reference to a singleton class. And also see for edited contents to help making the actual used case for what i want to use.

Comment: @RupamKairi sorry I don't understand your point when you  say " Because this way I need to to reference other variables of the class by hard-coding for all variables." This is a singleton. core and core1 are just two references to the same object, it looks like what you want to use, although I put pass in `__init__` just for you to fill with your needs, because they weren't so clear as now that you edited. My answer is the same as Serge actually, apart a little detail that looks unnecessary to me. I sked him for clarification.

Comment: @RupamKairi It's ok, actually that's necessary for singleton subclassing.